# Adding to an array random Ints and getting min and max

Tags: c#

I found some nice links about getting min and max That part I can figure out. I can create a new array of 10 spots of zero. I am assuming I need to run some form of for loop to get my 10 random values into the array. I just need to know how to do that so I can run my min max statements and print those.

My Code thus far

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication   
{
    public class Program
    {          
        public static void RandomArray() 
        {
            int[] numArray = new int[10];
            Random rand = new Random();

            for(int val = 0; val < 10; val++)
            {
                //Prints the next random value between 5 and 25
                Console.WriteLine(rand.Next(5,25));
            }    

        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RandomArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code lines look kind of scrambled there.

Comment: The code works it prints out 10 random numbers I just need to put in array so i can run more code for min and max forgive me if messing first day of c# school

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add the random number to the array all you need to do is change what you do inside the loop:

```
for(int val = 0; val < 10; val++)
{
    numArray[val]=rand.Next(5,25);
}
```

So now instead of printing them you are adding them to the array.

Take into account that if you want to call the min/max methods from the main it won't work since you don't have access to `numArray` there.

But you can call them inside `RandomArray` or change that method so that it returns an array.

Comment: Great ty So i should be able to go though and use numArray to find the min and max could you edit to sow me that code I have 5 min before i can green light your answer

Comment: Yes, but you would need to do this inside your `RandomArray` method

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the random number in the loop, but you also need to add the value to the array.

```
numArray[val] = rand.Next(5,25);
Console.WriteLine(numArray[val]);
```